# Drools Business Central Workbench - Test Scenario: List subproperty on object

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie

Is there a way to populate a List property on an object being tested under the "new style" test scenario?

I see some "legacy" test cases which seem to achieve this so am wondering if the new style test scenario handles this.

I added the List model to my test case, which enabled me to expand the sub-property on the object, however there is only one field available there, "empty" (boolean). Is there a way to add an object here? If it makes any difference, the model is an external java dependency.

**Update**

The reason I wasn't able to add the List of objects was because I didn't explicitly import that object dependency into the test. Once you import it you can follow the steps given in the answer below.

Comment: What are you talking about, "new style" and "legacy"? are you referring to a tutorial or some specific part of some documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible to manage a List property under the Test Scenario Editor.
Please consider the following example: A `Book` class with a `List<String>` property named *topics*.

[image]

Creating a new Test Scenario assets, please select the column where you need to add the `List` property, and in the right part of the editor select the property expanding the `Book` class, as shown below:

[image]

Pressing `Insert Data Ojbect` button will assign the selected List property to the selected column:

[image]

To fill the data in the `List` property, please double click on the `Insert value` cell, in the first scenario data row. A popup will appear. Its aim is to fill data inside a collection

[image]

To add a value, please press the `Add list value` link in the bottom part of the popup. Here, you'll be able to fill a single item on the list

[image]

Repeat this step for all the items you need to add to the list. When completed, simply press to `Save` button

[image]

The popup will close and you should see the previously selected data cell filled with a label similar to `List(2)`, the number represents the number of the items  in the list.

Comment: Thanks! In my version of business central (7.29) when I double click on the Insert Value cell, it just goes into text entry mode. I will investigate why it behaves like that for me.

Comment: @VladL That's weird. Anyway, my suggestion is to update your business central version (currently 7.54.0).